# Incorrect hover area with QGraphicsPathItem and QPainterPathStroker

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, drawing, qgraphicsitem

I am writing a class inheriting from `QGraphicsItemGroup` and its main child is a `QGraphicsPathItem`. The whole thing is used to draw polylines. I wanted to have a proper hover system for the lines, si I reimplemented the `shape` method of the object as follows:

```
def shape(self):
    stroker = QtWidgets.QPainterPathStroker()
    stroker.setWidth(10 * self.resolution)  # resolution handles zoom and stuff
    path = stroker.createStroke(self.__path.path()).simplified()
    return path
```

In the above snippet, `self.__path` is the `QGraphicsPathItem` I mentioned ealier.

---

To make things simple, here are a few pictures. The line I drew, that I see on the screen:

[image]

The hover area I want:

[image]

The hover area I currently have with the reimplemented `shape` method shown above:

[image]

As you guessed, such a selection area is hardly useful for any purpose. Worst of all, I tried to use the exact same method to generate the outlines of the line, then used `toFillPolygon` to generate a polygon that I rendered in the same object by adding a `QGraphicsPolygonItem` child to my object: the shape that appears on my screen is exactly what I want, but when I use the same path to create the hover area via `shape`, it gives me the useless hover area (image 3) instead.

So, do you know why the path obtained with the `QPainterPathStroker` allows me to display a polygon that seems to exactly correspond to the hover area I want, but when I use that path in `shape`, the obtained over area is wonky? If so, do you know how to fix this problem?